# How do I change the completed date for tasks in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, tasks

I would like to use outlook to record the date of on which I complete work related tasks. I often forget to change a task status to "completed" on the day that I actually complete the task.  When I select "complete" the next day, however, I would like the completed task to appear on the day I actually completed it, for record keeping, as opposed to appearing on the next day when I changed the status to "complete".  Is there a way that I can change the date completed?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Fay

Answer (score 3):

When you go to the tasks page, make sure you're in `simple view`, `right click, show fields, date completed` make sure this is in the `show fields` listing. 
Once you have this you can see the date of completion in the reading pane, select it and change it to the date of completion. You can type in a regular date (e.g. 1/1/11) and it will format it to the format you've chosen [image]

Comment: @phazer if this worked for you, be sure to select the green check mark to mark the answer as a resolution to the question

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer so the question can be closed.